# Sending data from javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I have a website which contains some JavaScript code.  On a different server, I have a python script.  I am trying to send data to the python script and then have the python script return some text.

The JavaScript calls the python file with a call like:

//server.example.com/cgi-bin/pythonscript.py?type=ball&color=blue

My first question is how do I read in those parameters (type=ball and color=blue) in the python script?  Would using any of these methods work:

```
    parameters=input() 

    or

    parameters=sys.argv[1:]

    or

    import cgi
    parameters=cgi.FieldStorage()
```

My second question is then how to I send data back to the JavaScript code.  Now, I will be sending text back using JSONP (JavaScript uses callback).  Will a simple print or return statement work as shown below?

```
    output_text='callback_func('+json.dump(output_info)+');'

    print(output_text)

    or

    return output_text
```

Thanks for the help!!!  It is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `cgi` module, then you use `FieldStorage` and `print` output

Taken from http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html - this can be used as a base that you just tweak slightly...

```
import cgi

print "Content-Type: text/html"     # HTML is following
print                               # blank line, end of headers
print "<TITLE>CGI script output</TITLE>"
print "<H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>"

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if "name" not in form or "addr" not in form:
    print "<H1>Error</H1>"
    print "Please fill in the name and addr fields."
    return
print "<p>name:", form["name"].value
print "<p>addr:", form["addr"].value
```